# How do I flatten nested Avro records in a Pig query?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, avro

Avro schema looks like this:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "name1",
  "fields" :
  [
    {
      "name" : "f1",
      "type" : "string"
    },
    {
      "name" : "f2",
      "type" :
      {
        "type" : "array",
        "items" :
        {
          "type" : "record",
          "name" : "name2",
          "fields" :
          [
            {
              "name" : "time",
              "type" : [ "float", "int", "double", "long" ]
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After reading it in Pig:

```
grunt> A = load 'data' using AvroStorage();
grunt> DESCRIBE A;
A: {f1: chararray,f2: {ARRAY_ELEM: (time: (FLOAT: float,INT: int,DOUBLE: double,LONG: long))}}
```

What I want is probably a bag of `(f1:chararray, timestamp:double)`. This is what I did:

```
grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1, f2.time AS timestamp;
grunt> DESCRIBE B;
B: {f1: chararray,timestamp: {(time: (FLOAT: float,INT: int,DOUBLE: double,LONG: long))}}
```

So how do I flatten this record?

I'm new to Pig, Avro and don't know what I'm trying to do even makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide sample input data and output which you are expecting?